# BigQuery - How to query the number of columns in a table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to query a table to get how many columns in that table and the name of each column. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361414/bigquery-get-the-total-number-of-columns-in-a-bigquery-table) tells us how to do it in BQ command line interface, but can we do it using query?

Comment: The way your question is asked - the answer is very solid 'NO'. But - there is ALWAYS workaround! I would suggest you to give us your use-case and practical value (unless this was just challenge type of the question) so we can help you to address your real problem vs. above question

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Hi Mikhail thank you for the help I'll update the post with the use case

Answer (score 1):

From the following doc, it seems that the meta-tables won't give this kind of information. So, I guess the answer is no.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#using_meta-tables

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT
   count(*)
 FROM
   `project`.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS
where 
    table_name="table_name"
```